# Sometimes Ctrl+Enter works, sometimes not

Tags: feature-request

When you edit an answer or question you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and finish (same as sending an email on gmail). This works in a couple of other places, but not when you are submitting a question or answer, you have to physically click the button.

Is this a bug or feature by design?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Didn't know about this.